# Use external data for a Leaflet Choropleth map

Tags: leaflet, vue.js

I'm using Leaflet.js in a Vue project.

When I create the counties within a US State my GeoJSON looks like:

```
    {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "GEO_ID": "0500000US45045",
            "STATE": "45",
            "COUNTY": "045",
            "name": "Greenville",
            "CENSUSAREA": 785.12,
     },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  -82.193006,
                  34.686303
                ],
```

And the code to generate the map

```
this.geoJsonLayer  = L.geoJson(this.geoSC, {
         style: this.statestyle,
         preferCanvas: true,
         onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature,
       }).addTo(this.map);
```

And

```
   statestyle(feature) {
      return {
      fillColor: this.getColorBrewer(feature.properties["CENSUSAREA"])     
    
    };
    },
```

`getColorBrewer` is a function to select a color based upon the value of the this.geoSC CensusArea data.

This all works fine IF the Census data is on the original GeoJSON object.

How do I use a separate object such as

```
 var Countydata = [{
        "GEO_ID": "0500000US45045",
        "STATE": "45",
        "COUNTY": "045",
        "name": "Greenville",
        "LSAD": "County",
        "CENSUSAREA": 785.12,       
      },
    {
        "GEO_ID": "0500000US45047",
        "STATE": "45",
        "COUNTY": "047",
        "name": "Greenwood",
        "LSAD": "County",
        "CENSUSAREA": 454.726,
       
      },
```

Currently I'm doing:

```
   statestyle(feature) {
    let newCensus = this.Countydata.find(el => el.GEO_ID=== feature.properties.GEO_ID);

      return {
      fillColor: this.getColorBrewer(newCensus ["CENSUSAREA"])   
    };
    },
```

Is there a standard that I should be following?

Comment: It would be probably more economic to do this in `onEachFeature` function and store value in some feature property, so search would be executed only once for each feature at load time, and not at each feature styling call.